# Why is value not adding correctly?

Tags: php, mysql

This code is in a foreach loop which should handle a large 'checklist' style input. This particular section should store a number in a database which helps re-order the list.

Testing this code in its own standalone file seems to work and shows the desired result, but put into practice it doesn't work.

```
// Get the number we need for the disp_order
$order_query = $db_connect->query("SELECT disp_order FROM procedure_data WHERE procedure_id = ".$pd_p_id." ORDER BY disp_order DESC LIMIT 1");
$order = $order_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ($order['disp_order'] == NULL) {
    $calculated_disp_order = 1;
} else {
    $calculated_disp_order = $order['disp_order']+1;
};

// Close this, we don't need it anymore
$order_query->close();

$stmt = $db_connect->prepare("INSERT INTO procedure_data VALUES 
(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
$stmt->bind_param("iissss", $pd_p_id, $calculated_disp_order, 
$pd_task, $pd_action_type, $pd_action, $pd_notes);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

`$order['disp_order']` returns the correct value of 11, but should be increased by 1 at `$calculated_disp_order = $order['disp_order']+1;`. Instead it's keeping its value of 11.

Comment: `$calculated_disp_order = float($order['disp_order'])+1;`

Comment: Where is the code for a loop? Have you checked what `$order['disp_order']` contains?

Comment: Roy, thank you! I used floatval which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`floatval()` was needed for the following line:

`$calculated_disp_order = floatval($order['disp_order'])+1;`